# ST_Intersects not working with ST_Expand from a point

Tags: postgis

I would like to do a real simple thing:
I have a bounding box B1 (ST_MakeEnvelope) and I want to see if a square of 100 meters around a lat/long position intersects the other bounding box (B1).

I have tried to do this :

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(
        ST_MakeEnvelope(2.3400235176086426, 48.87195488537595, 2.3521900177001953, 48.86635145037327, 4326)::geometry,
            ST_Expand(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.888275146484375, 47.89788468044446), 4326)::geometry, 100));
```

This should return false, because the point position if more than 100 km from my B1 bounding box ...

But I always get :

```
 st_intersects
---------------
 t
```

Where is my mistake?

---

After @zimmi's answer I did :

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(
            ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(2.3400235176086426, 48.87195488537595, 2.3521900177001953, 48.86635145037327, 4326)::geometry, 3857),
                ST_Expand(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.888275146484375, 47.89788468044446), 4326)::geometry, 3857), 100));
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All EPSG:4326 geometries calculations are done with degrees instead of kilometeres. Use ST_Transform to reproject your data into a CRS that uses metric units.

Comment: Right, you expand by 100 degrees now.